# Require JSDoc on all functions with JSCS

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jscs

I'm using [JSCS](http://jscs.info/) to enforce a consistent code style in one of my projects.

Is there a way to use JSCS to check that every function has some JSDoc?

Something that would say this is invalid:

```
var add = function(x, y) {
    return x + y;
};
```

But this is valid:

```
/**
 * Adds two numbers together
 * @param {number} x
 * @param {number} y
 * @returns The sum of x and y
 */
var add = function(x, y) {
    return x + y;
};
```

Comment: are you using a ide or simple text editor? many have plugins to generate the initial doc code if not already there

Comment: I'm using an IDE which can generate JSDoc, but other members of my team may not. I'd like the check enforced as part of the build to make sure everyone adds the appropriate JSDoc.

Comment: are you using grunt? (for the build)

Comment: Yep I'm using grunt :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [jscs-jsdoc](https://github.com/jscs-dev/jscs-jsdoc) does it! It comes as a plugin for JSCS, and you can include the following in your `.jscsrc`:

```
"plugins": ["jscs-jsdoc"],
"jsDoc": {
    "enforceExistence": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using grunt you could use a [grunt reg ex check](https://github.com/thekua/grunt-regex-check).

This allows you to run regEx based checks on the contents. 
The example on the github repo is to test for console.log's but could be used to find function without jsdoc comments.

Not ideal, but would do the job, proving the regEx are up to scratch

Comment: Ideally I'd have something a little neater than this - I might go for this option if there isn't a way to do it with JSCS or similar.

Comment: yeah I'd have assumed there would be something better but couldn't find a ready made solution